# Create new web app in exist-db 5.3.0 (and import old from 4.3.1)

Tags: exist-db

I just updated exist-db from 4.3.1 to 5.3.0. And now, there is no "Application/New Application" button in eXide. So it's unclear how to create new applications. A saw the link to yeoman-based generator-exist tool in patch notes. But i don't understand how to create application in the db. So please give me instructions on how to properly create an application in the new exist-db version.
And bonus question: how to move applications from 4.3.1 to 5.3.0? (i don't upgrade db and create new clear db instead). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As of eXide 3.0.0, the recommended method for generating new applications is via [generator-exist](https://github.com/eXist-db/generator-exist), a command-line tool. As described in the eXide repository's [README file](https://github.com/eXist-db/eXide#note-concerning-exide-300):

> eXide 3.0.0 removes the app generation feature as it was generating outdated code with potential security risks. We recommend the much better yeoman-based [generator-exist](https://github.com/eXist-db/generator-exist) for eXist-db.

So instead of creating an application from within eXist, you now create them on the command line and install them as EXPath Packages.

If you have an existing app installed on an eXist 4.3.1 system, you can still download it in eXide via "Application > Download app". To install your downloaded app package in eXist 5.3.0, open eXist's "Dashboard > Package Manager".

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thank you!
But how i can change version of my application? In previous version i used "application info", but now there is no this menu item.

Comment: I successfully uploaded .xar exported from 4.3.1. But new .xar files created with yeoman always cause an error "Missing descriptor from package".

Comment: To change the version number of your application, open the package's `expath-pkg.xml` document and edit the root `<package>` element's `@version` attribute.

Comment: Regarding the "Missing descriptor from package" error that you're getting when installing a package generated by generator-exist, this indicates either a missing `expath-pkg.xml`, `repo.xml`, or an expected value therein. The generator-exist app shouldn't generate invalid package metadata, so could you please open an issue via https://github.com/eXist-db/generator-exist/issues/new/choose to report the problem?